# How to disable link on Button but when I click on card link should be work

Tags: javascript, html

I am Using card and when i click on card its work fine. Now i have added three buttons in cards when i click on button then card link also call. i just want to perform different action from button but not card link.

[image: When i click on Pizza its working fine but when i click on S, M, L Buttons then same link calling on these button]

This is code:

```
<li class="t-Cards-item #CARD_MODIFIERS#" data-id="#ID#" >
  <div class="click t-Card" >
    <a href="javascript:void(null);" class="t-Card-wrap" data-id="#ID#">
      <div class="t-Card-icon u-color #CARD_COLOR#"><span class="t-Icon fa #CARD_ICON#"><span class="t-Card-initials" role="presentation">#CARD_INITIALS#</span></span></div>
      <div class="t-Card-titleWrap"><h3 class="t-Card-title">#CARD_TITLE#</h3>
      <h4 class="t-Card-subtitle">#CARD_SUBTITLE#</h4></div>
        <div id="outer">
        <div class="inner"><button  class="msgBtn"   >S</button></div>
        <div class="inner"><button  class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">M</button></div>
        <div class="inner"><button  class="msgBtnBack">L</button></div>
        </div>
       
      <div class="t-Card-body">
        <div class="t-Card-desc">#CARD_TEXT#</div>
        <div class="t-Card-info">#CARD_SUBTEXT#</div>              
          
      </div>
      <span class="t-Card-colorFill u-color #CARD_COLOR#"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
   
</li>
```

Comment: Use `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Where to use this?

Comment: inside button's function

Comment: This is invalid HTML to begin with - nesting `button` into `a` is not allowed, since those are both considered "interactive" elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### The Problem

Assume there are two divs with two different buttons on them.

```
<div onClick={handleOutter}>
  <div onClick={handleInner}>
    // some content ...
  </div>
</div>
```

calling `handleOutter` will call the `handleInner` function. this is the default behavior of event propagation in your elements. more info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture) documentation.

##### The Solution

You can stop event propagation in the child elements by adding `event.stopPropagation()` in the handler function in this way:

```
const btn = document.getElementById('myParentElement');

btn.onclick = function (event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // ...
}
```

more info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) documentation.